# How can I save multiple values selected in a list?

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I have a form with the dynamically generated XML and by dynamically, it was programmatically created during getForm function. I want to save the value I selected as a key:value pair to be stored in a table column:

```
<field name ="frequency" type="list"
    label="Frequency"
        description="Frequency of sending report subscribed."
        option_on ="Yes"
        option_off ="Yes"
        multiple="true"
>
```

Now it enables multiple selection, but when I save the form, the values I selected did not reflect.

I have this as reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php

But my objective is to save the selected values.

[image]
What could be wrong?

The image above displays the custom field I created. However, those that I have selected "one" and "three" are not saved in the database.

Comment: I updated the question http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5480/creating-custom-field-type-multiselect-list-how-to-save-the-values?noredirect=1#comment9505_5480 .
This is how i did it, with creating a new custom field as a multiselect list, hope it help you.

Comment: Could you give more code. The snippet lacks both the options tags and the closing field tag. Or I am misunderstanding the question totally? (Not entirely unlikely...)

Comment: I just posted the code to show that I set the input field to multiple @VilleNiemi I don't intend to post the entire field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue with the ff. code:

```
$mydata = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform', array(), 'array');
```

I found out that I do not need to check the field if it is an array or not, I have created an blank array

```
$fils[$new_filter['name']] = $mydata[$new_filter['name']];
```

from the code above, this is the interpretation:

```
$fils['frequency'] = $mydata['frequency']
```

the variable $mydata['frequency'] automatically contains the multiple values I selected from the dropdown which has an attribute     multiple = "true" in the XML file.