# Is it possible to edit the SQL custom field to be multi-select?

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field, form-fields-types, sql

I want to be able to select multiple values with the SQL custom field. Is this possible? When I use a query which as multiple results, I can only pick one.

I found this post: [Creating custom field type multiselect list - how to save the values?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5480/creating-custom-field-type-multiselect-list-how-to-save-the-values) But this is for creating a new custom field, I would like to change the SQL field a bit. I'm using joomla 3.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating/editing the field, set `Multiple` option to `Yes`. Or edit `Fields - SQL` plugin to enable multiple option globally for all SQL fields.